# What is the idiomatic way to run a Node.js project

Tags: node.js

what is the idiomatic way to run a Node.js project that has package.json with '"main": "index.js"' inside? do I run something like "node run" or "npm run" ?

The `package.json` file:

```
{
"name": "bandymas",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

And index.js file exists. So what is the idiomatic way?

Comment: `npm start`, you create a start script

Comment: it is easy to create start script. But why then we gave main specified?  I just assume that if I it has the main specified so it is used bu some command like "node run". Or something. Like Leiningen has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `start` script to your `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "bandymas",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This way, you can start your project by just running `npm start`.